# What locations should I use for dumping flash memory from electronic components in HDDs?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, hard-disk, dd

From my understanding , the electronic components in HDDs can store memory in flash memory chips. I am not interested in the disc platters. I would like to dump only this flash memory using a Linux distro to examine it.

What are the locations I should be using to access this memory - eg with `dd`?

Answer (score 1):

The contents of flash chips in hard drives aren't accessible using tools such as `dd`. To read them you'd typically use a JTAG interface (if you can find one on your drive's PCB), or a special serial-style connector on the drive, or just probe the chips directly; see [this post](https://hackmag.com/security/hdd-root/) for examples of the former approaches. It might be possible to read them using vendor-specific commands, but I'm not aware of any current drive for which these have been reverse-engineered. To understand how a drive works you'd also need to read its service sections, which are reserved areas of the platters used to store the drive's software; the post linked to above also has examples of that (using vendor-specific commands). The link to the source-code is broken but it's easy enough to fix, I'll leave it as an exercise to discourage readers who shouldn't really be venturing anywhere near it...

[Hard disk hacking](http://spritesmods.com/?art=hddhack) provides lots more information on this topic.

Comment: Why do you discourage readers from venturing to the source code?

Comment: I'm only discouraging readers who aren't capable of working out for themselves where to find it.